# How to ignore unused imports from wildcard imports in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I would like to ignore "unused import *** from wildcard import". How to add this warning [W0614] to the existing warnings in VS Code settings

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678503/is-it-possible-to-ignore-specific-warnings-with-visual-studio-codes-linter

Comment: Nah! I want to have the existing warnings and need to add a new warning to the ignore list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using PyCharm. But if you dont want to i think in the instllation folder of VS Code there is a .cfg file you should try find all .cfg file and then check the content of the files. And in one of there is something about ignoreing errors. I dont remember because nowadays I use PyCharm instead of using VS code for Python.

Comment: I agree. But pycharm is very slow compared to VS Code. So, I switched out from pycharm and wanted to use VS Cute. Also there are lot of extensions available which make programming a lot easier in VS Code.

Comment: You are right! But in "VS Cute" :) there are very few extensions which is Python oriented.